# Deployment of ShinyApp on webserver results in the error: character argument expected

Tags: shiny, deployment, version-control

The ShinyApp can be deployed in R without error messages but when deploying it on the internal webserver the error "character argument expected" appears.

Just to add the code has been created with a different R version and a docker has been built. Later changes have been made with a different R package. Does someone know, if there is an error in the code or does the problem derive from using different R versions?